# Populate the drop-down menu from the Joomla database

Tags: dropdown

This is my code with a classic html dropdown with large list, and a button that executes the querry with the selected value:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="lista" method="post" action="">
<select id="broj" name="name">                      
<option value="0">--Odaberi vrh--</option>
<option value="1">Maglić</option>
<option value="2">Vlasulja</option>
<option value="3">Veliki Oštrikovac</option>
...
<option value="73">Velika Lelija</option>
<option value="74">Bregoč</option>
<option value="75">Kozje strane</option>
<option value="76">Cincar</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
<?php
$peak = $_POST['name'];
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
----querry with $peak
}
?>
```

This is solution from @jamesgarrett where the dropdown menu is populated from the Joomla database:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('peak_name');
$query->from($db->qn('#__peaks'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$peaks_list = $db->loadColumn();

// you could just echo out as you go if you prefer, but instead here we build up the html as a single string.
$peaks_select  = '<select name="name" id="peaks">';
$peaks_select .= '<option value="">-- Select Peak --</option>';

// here we use the peak_name for the value, whereas usually you set the value to the id of the table row. we're assuming there won't be any double quotes in these names.
foreach($peaks_list as $p){
    $peaks_select .= '<option value="' . $p . '">' . $p . '</option>';  
}
$peaks_select .= '</select>';

echo $peaks_select;
```

But I never succeeded to create the other part of the code with the button which will execute querry.

Comment: Are you asking how to make an HTML select field and build select options using a loop? If not then you may need to clarify to what ‘the dropdown menu’ refers.

Comment: Yes, I ask how to make an HTML select field and build select options using a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('peak_name');
$query->from($db->qn('#__peaks'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$peaks_list = $db->loadColumn();

// you could just echo out as you go if you prefer, but instead here we build up the html as a single string.
$peaks_select  = '<select name="name" id="peaks">';
$peaks_select .= '<option value="">-- Select Peak --</option>';

// here we use the peak_name for the value, whereas usually you set the value to the id of the table row. we're assuming there won't be any double quotes in these names.
foreach($peaks_list as $p){
    $peaks_select .= '<option value="' . $p . '">' . $p . '</option>';  
}
$peaks_select .= '</select>';


?><html>
<body>
<form name="lista" method="post" action="">
<?php echo $peaks_select; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
<?php
$peak = $_POST['name'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // ----query with $peak
}
```

Comment: Just one more question. I need to make a variable $peak with the selected value. How? 
 <form name="list" method="post" action="">
<?php
 $peak = $_POST['name'];
?>
But not working

Comment: A submitted field is accessible server side by having a name attribute. I have edited my answer with name="name".

Comment: I'm sorry, but my knowledge in this field is very limited. So far I have accessed the selected value with the POST method. How can I do it now? I did an update to my first question where I explained the situation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added the form markup from your edited post around the select.